# Clutching functions of 2-sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

One way to construct vector bundles over spheres is given by the so-called **clutching maps**, that is maps (between topological spaces) of the form 
$$f : \mathbb{S}^{k-1} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R}).$$ 
Through those maps we can form a quotient of $(\mathbb{D}_+^{k} \times \mathbb{R}^n) \coprod (\mathbb{D}_-^{k} \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ (which I'll call by X), by identifying $(x,u) \sim (x, f_x (u))$ along the common boundary $\mathbb{S}^{k-1}$, of the corresponding disks and along with that construction we have an one-to-one correspondence $$[\mathbb{S}^{k-1}, GL_n(\mathbb{R})] \cong Vect^n(\mathbb{S}^k).$$

Now, I'm intrested in the special case where $k=n=2$. Is "trivial" from the Hairy Ball Theorem that the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ isn't trivial and we can recover it by the aforementioned construction. So, although the diffeomorhpism of
$$h : T(\mathbb{S}^2) \rightarrow X,$$ 
seems quite reasonable, I can't find what's the inverse of it, since on equivalence classes needs some attention/subtlety which I can't find at the moment. Could you please help me out with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the first answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25659/tangent-sphere-bundle-over-sphere

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have seen that and to be honest I understand exactly what is says, but for some reason I'm getting stuck to write down explicitly the inverse map. Do you know how can we send the classes on $\partial  \mathbb{D}_{\pm}^k$ to $T(\mathbb{S}^2)$?